# Prevent iptables from blocking outgoing access

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall

Apache on Centos6 allows access from remote clients.  The server, however, does not allow outgoing access (i.e. `ping google.com`, `ssh`, etc) unless I disable the iptables.

Why is iptables blocking outgoing access, and how do I prevent it from doing so?

```
[Michael@vps2 ~]$ ping google.com
^C
[Michael@vps2 ~]$ ping localhost
PING localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
^C
--- localhost.localdomain ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 789ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.019/0.019/0.019/0.000 ms
[Michael@vps2 ~]$ sudo /etc/init.d/iptables status
Table: mangle
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Table: filter
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:1443
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:10000
6    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
7    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:1337
8    DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

[Michael@vps2 ~]$ sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  380 41335 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ies-lm
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ndmp
    2   168 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:menandmice-dns
   23  1208 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 352 packets, 55019 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
[Michael@vps2 ~]$ sudo /etc/init.d/iptables stop
iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: mangle filter   [  OK  ]
iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]
[Michael@vps2 ~]$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.4.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ord36s04-in-f110.1e100.net (172.217.4.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from ord36s04-in-f110.1e100.net (172.217.4.110): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=1.00 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1209ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.002/1.045/1.088/0.043 ms
[Michael@vps2 ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to enable Related and Estabilished packets. Put it on top of the rules list.

```
# iptables -I INPUT 1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

moreover, the ICMP is a different protocol than TCP and UDP, you should explicitly allow it. I usually allow ICMP completely, since blocking it can sometimes create problems with stuff like fragmentation.

```
# iptables -I INPUT 2 -p icmp  -j ACCEPT
```

one more thing: instead of adding a "drop all" rule, you can change the policy of the chain:

```
# iptables -P INPUT DROP
```